# JMS Serializer Exclude Entity field in Symfony2 Controller

Tags: json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have an Entity of mine which I would like to expose in a JSON API that I'm developing, the problem is that in this particular controller, there is just one field which I don't want to expose. Is there a way to exclude it from serialization from within the controller?

I know I can annotate my entity so the serializer just passes by that field, but what happens in all the other cases? This is really the exception.

Answer (score 5):

You can assign each property to a group,
then define that group in a context when serializing
from the controller.

Your entity:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotations as Serializer;

class Comment
{
    /** @Serializer\Groups({"main", "secondary"}) */
    private $id;

    /** @Serializer\Groups({"main", "secondary"}) */
    private $title;

    /** @Serializer\Groups({"main", "secondary"}) */
    private $name;

    /** @Serializer\Groups({"main"}) */
    private $email;

    /** @Serializer\Groups({"main", "secondary"}) */
    private $message;
}
```

Then in your controller

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

$serializer->serialize(
    new Comment(),
    'json',
    SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('secondary'))
);
```

In this example, the email field is excluded from the serialized data, but only for the group named `secondary`. You can of course call these groups whatever you like.

Comment: In other words... no.